# Creating a hash from several Java string objects

Tags: java, hash, md5, hashcode, sha

What would be the fastest and more robust (in terms of uniqueness) way for implementing a method like

```
public abstract String hash(String[] values);
```

The `values[]` array has 100 to 1,000 members, each of a which with few dozen characters, and the method needs to be run about 10,000 times/sec on a different `values[]` array each time.

Should a long string be build using a `StringBuilder` buffer and then a hash method invoked on the buffer contents, or is it better to keep invoking the hash method for each string from `values[]`?

Obviously a hash of at least 64 bits is needed (e.g., MD5) to avoid collisions, but is there anything simpler and faster that could be done, at the same quality?

For example, what about

```
public String hash(String[] values)
{
    long result = 0;

    for (String v:values)
    {
        result += v.hashCode();
    }

    return String.valueOf(result);
}
```

Comment: That approach looks reasonable.  You may want to store the hash value in a field so you don't have to recalculate it every time, as long as you update it every time your String[] changes.

Comment: Sure, but in the application in question the values[] array changes all the time. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the simple implementation using Objects class available from Java 7.

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return Objects.hash(this.variable1, this.variable2);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Definitely don't use plain addition due to its linearity properties, but you can modify your code just slightly to achieve very good dispersion.

```
public String hash(String[] values) {
  long result = 17;
  for (String v:values) result = 37*result + v.hashCode();
  return String.valueOf(result);
}
```

Comment: Is 17 enough, or a longer prime would be needed? And what about collisions across tens of millions of invocations?

Comment: Collisions are unavoidable however you turn it. If it is such a concern, you should use something stronger and with more than 64 bits.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't provide a 64 bit hash, but given the title of the question it's probably worth mentioning that since Java 1.7 there is [java.util.Objects#hash(Object...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-).

Answer (score 2):

You should watch out for creating weaknesses when combining methods. (The java hash function and your own). I did a little research on cascaded ciphers, and this is an example of it. (the addition might interfere with the internals of hashCode().

The internals of hashCode() look like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
```

so adding numbers together will cause the last characters of all strings in the array to just be added, which doesn't lower the randomness (this is already bad enough for a hash function).

If you want real pseudorandomness, take a look at the [FNV](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) hash algorithm. It is the fastest hash algorithm out there that is especially designed for use in HashMaps.

It goes like this:

```
    long hash = 0xCBF29CE484222325L;
    for(String s : strings)
    {
        hash ^= s.hashCode();
        hash *= 0x100000001B3L;
    }
```

^ This is not the actual implementation of FNV as it takes ints as input instead of bytes, but I think it works just as well.

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure this is faster than the other, simple approaches suggested here? Randomness is probably better, by the looks of it.

Comment: I never claimed it is faster than anything else. In fact, the speed is identical to the other answers. (assuming addition and xor are equal in terms of speed)

Comment: "real randomness" -- nothing of the sort found here.

Comment: You're sharp. Changed to 'pseudorandomness', which I meant from the start.

Answer (score 1):

First, hash code is typically numeric, e.g. `int`. Moreover your version of hash function create int and then makes its string representation that IMHO does not have any sense.

I'd improve your hash method as following:

```
public int hash(String[] values) {
    long result = 0;
   for (String v:values) {
        result = result * 31 + v.hashCode();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Take a look on `hashCode()` implemented in class `java.lang.String`

Comment: I agree, but the return type is an application formality. Other than that, your suggestion is similar to Marko's. Would it be OK with respect to collisions across tens of millions of invocations?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why is that a problem?